# Is it possible to store PART of the URL in to a variable or somehow using cypress and use it later?

Tags: javascript, variables, url, cypress

i need to store the url from my website in to an URL and use part of it for an API call

Comment: Can you please add a code example as well as what your request or URL looks like?

Comment: I don't have a code example because i am just starting to write the test, it will be am 'cy.visit("URL")' and i have to store part of my URL to use it later

Comment: .......com/project/1f2c8ee3-9b7a-422d-8edd-b81a2bdf286d/ *i need this part* fa031c9f-13d9-4d50-bf52-fe4dbe221b1f *until here* /plan

i need to take the string between the last two "/"

Comment: Hi. As I understand, you need to store the uuid. Let me ask you, why you want to store it from the URL? why you don't intercept for GET request instead? having an object ID in the URL, involves a fetch request. This will be much better in terms of performance and readability. ...but, in case you are limited by any kind of circumstances to intercept the request, then I recommend using the simplest uuid regex to extract it from the URL.

Comment: @AlexIzbas can you help me on how to intercept it for GET request.... the problem is that i am ultra noob using API calls..... is there a specific way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

***...coming from the comments, I leave an answer here:***

With version `6.0.0`, Cypress introduced a new command: `.intercept()`.

`.intercept()` allows you to manage the behavior of network requests. It supports fetch, it can intercept both request and response of your app API calls and so much more, official docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Syntax).

Related to your case, make sure you declare your intercept command before the proper fetch action, let's say on the top of the test. Then, simply call it below in the body of the test by its alias:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '/project/*').as('myObject')

// ...


cy.wait('@myObject').its('response.body.data.id').then(objUUID => {
// here is your uuid
   cy.log(objUUID) 
})
```

Note, that any other action related to this uuid should be done inside above callback: `.then(objUUID => {})`. In case you need it shared between different tests, then intercept your request inside `.beforeEach()` hook and assign the uuid in a context shared variable, however, this is a bad practice (more about aliases and variables, [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Return-Values))

Comment: makes sens, thanks for your time to give such an elaborate question.
In my case, the uuid is dynamic, meaning when everythime i create a "new project" it has a different url(i need the exact part of url that is dynamic).... i hope i am clear :)

Comment: i meant *answer not question!